# Можно ли сказать "я люблю игратьСЯ с братиком"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология

Можно ли сказать "я люблю играть**ся** с братиком", или правильно только "я люблю игра**ть** с братиком"? Почему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Глагол **играться** в значении "играть" можно употреблять, но только в разговорной речи.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка:

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=262653&v=full

Comment: Не знаю, в какой разговорной речи Вы хотите употребить этот глагол. Речь идёт о КОНТЕКСТЕ: именно в ЭТОЙ форме управления и именно с этим предлогом. Так может сказать только абсолютно безграмотный человек. (Приведите ещё пример : играть С мячом или бояться ОТ собаки!) И не надо мне ссылаться на интернет.

Comment: @user183861 в [МАС](https://www.slovari.ru/search.aspx?s=0&p=3068&di=vmas&wi=20170), в [БТС](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x&v=full) и др. зафиксирована эта информация.

Comment: Aer, после user183861 следует ставить запятую, это обращение!

Comment: а чем обоснована авторитетность ссылки?

Answer (score 1):

**Я люблю играться с братиком.**..

Сказать-то так можно, но зачем так говорить? Какая-то жеманность и манерность чувствуется в этой фразе. Дети играются ... Я слышала это выражение от очень интеллигентной  соседки по даче, и даже тогда (в детском возрасте) оно мне казалась странным – слащавым, неестественным. Это же всё-таки не язык народной поэзии,  а обычная обиходная речь, и стиль должен быть **нейтральным**.

**Тем не менее глагол "играться" в современном русском языке чувствует себя превосходно.**

**Во-первых, он вполне легитимен**: **это возвратный залог глагола.**

**Грамматическая справка**. В общем случае  субъект, отнесенный к возвратному глаголу, совершает  действие, направленное на себя, прямой объект при этом отсутствует.

**Но существуют частные значения возвратности** (в Грамматике-80 выделяются шесть таких частных случаев): 1) **собственно возвратное** (субъект действия одновременно является объектом действия): умывать – умываться, одевать – одеваться;  2) **взаимно-возвратное** (действие совершается несколькими субъектами, они же и объекты действия): целоваться, обниматься, судиться, ссориться,  бороться (**это как раз наш случай**); 3) **безобъектно-возвратное** (действие или состояние характерно для данного субъекта):  собака кусается, крапива жжётся. И т.д.

**Во-вторых, глагол "играться"** в современном языке  используется **довольно часто**, но только не в значении, указанном в словаре: ИГРАТЬСЯ 2. Нар.-разг. =Играть (1 зн.). И. с ребёнком. Глагол **политизировался**, отошел от народно-поэтической темы и получил **ироническую стилевую окраску**.

**Примеры**

1) Они хотят заниматься своими прямыми обязанностями, а не в партийные игры **играться!** Хватит шутки шутить и **играться** в молодежные игры! Вот что, липовый друг, я тебе не Литвинов, а ты мне не Чемберлен, и нам с тобой нечего в дипломатию **играться**.

**2) Иронический подтекст:** Не разрешают им, видите ли, в кукол на уроках **играться**.

3) **А это 19 век (пока еще нейтральный стиль):** ― Ну, хорошо! будем **играться** в индейцев! ― говорит Тема. [Н. Г. Гарин-Михайловский. Детство Темы (1892)]

Answer (score 0):

Глагол "играется" применим в следующих случаях:

1. Эта музыкальная пьеса играется в быстром темпе.
2. Эта шахматная партия играется очень долго.

Answer (score 0):

Так часто говорят. Просто, допустим, в рассказе я бы написала слово "играться" в том случае, когда бы по сюжету дети в конце концов до чего-то доигрались, дошалились.

Comment: Вы бы, как говорите, написали бы: «Игрались и доигрались»? «Шалились и дошалились»?

Answer (score -1):

Можно ли сказать "я люблю игратьСЯ с братиком" или правильно только "я люблю играть с братиком"?
Правильным будет только второй вариант. Суффиксы -СЯ, -СЬ считаются возвратными и обозначают, что действие направлено на себя. Например, "умыватьСЯ" значит умывать самого себя; "лечиться" - лечить самого себя. Сравните: умывать кого-то, лечить кого-то.
Кроме того, глагол "играть"  является ПЕРЕХОДНЫМ, а "играться"  НЕПЕРЕХОДНЫМ. Но, скорее всего, этот грамматический признак в данном случае является не определяющим.

Comment: >> *Суффиксы -СЯ, -СЬ считаются возвратными и обозначают, что действие направлено на себя. Например, "умыватьСЯ" значит умывать самого себя; "лечиться" - лечить самого себя. Сравните: умывать кого-то, лечить кого-то.*     Кусаться – кусать самого себя, драться – драть самого себя и т.д.

Comment: Без комментариев. Не надо "лепить" под одну гребёнку все возможные формы глаголов. Я привела пример.

Comment: Но аргументация-то неправильная. Поэтому и ответ неправильный.